# how to reshape arrays in python like in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, reshape, valueerror

This is the matlab code that I am trying to replicate in python.

```
   a=zeros(Steps,2,2);

   for i=1:1:Steps %some calculation and loops
       [b(i), a(i,:,:)]=meanT(D,t); % another function
   end  

   a=reshape(a,Steps,2,2);


function [b a]=meanT(Data,trimmingPercentage)
     q=7;
    x=sort(Data);
    b1=x(1+q:end-q);
    b=mean(b1);
    a=cov([real(b1).' imag(b1).']);

end
```

Matlab writes a as two arrays. Then the mean(D,t) function returns two arguments where a is in the form of a 2x2 matrix. (Steps=1 here). I want to know what a(1,:,:) does and how I can replicate the reshape matlab function in python. The resulting a after reshaping is

```
   1.0e-05 *

    0.8058         0


(:,:,2) =

     0     0
```

How can I make python do this? For now I get the meanT function to return a as a 2x2 matrix but I'm not sure if the for loop and reshape are doing what I need them to do.

```
a=np.zeros((2,Steps,2))
for i in range(Steps):
   [b[i], a[:,i,:]]=meanT(D,t)
a=np.reshape(a,Steps,2)
```

But it shows me the error "ValueError: Non-string object detected for the array ordering. Please pass in 'C', 'F', 'A', or 'K' instead"

Comment: You aren't using `np.reshape` right.  `np.reshape(a, newshape, order='C')` - `a` is the array, `newshape` is supposed to be `tuple`, the new shape.  The first argument is an optional `order`.  You gave it a number 2.

Comment: I can't help you with the `matlab`, since you don't provide enough information to replicate it in an `Octave` session.

Comment: Does the edit help?